# Unknown ArrayIndexOutOfBounds: 1 exception

Tags: java, arrays, minecraft, bukkit

In this game called minecraft, which all of you have probably heard of, is great for getting to learn java and more about libraries. However, Me and my friend were trying to code a plugin for fun and we fell upon this huge ArrayIndexOutOfBounds error. I need to know what is the problem with this. From what i gathered, the problem was in line 53.

```
package com.dillyg10.pvpprotect;

import com.earth2me.essentials.Essentials;
import com.earth2me.essentials.User;
import com.earth2me.essentials.UserMap;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.EventPriority;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.entity.EntityDamageByEntityEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerCommandPreprocessEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerQuitEvent;
import org.bukkit.plugin.Plugin;
import org.bukkit.plugin.PluginLoader;
import org.bukkit.plugin.PluginManager;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
import org.bukkit.scheduler.BukkitScheduler;

public class PvpProtect extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {
    public Map<Player, Integer> tagged = new HashMap();

    public void onEnable() {
        if (getEss() == null) {
            System.out.println("You must have Essentials installed");
            getPluginLoader().disablePlugin(this);
            return;
        }
        Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
        Bukkit.getScheduler().scheduleSyncRepeatingTask(this, new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Player[] removeUser = new Player[] {null};
                Player[] addUser = new Player[] {null};
                int[] x = new int[] {0};
                int rx = 0;
                int ax = 0;
                for (Player p : PvpProtect.this.tagged.keySet()) {
                    int i = ((Integer)PvpProtect.this.tagged.get(p)).intValue();
                    i--;
                    if (i == 0) {
                        p.sendMessage("§aYou are no longer pvp-tagged! You are free to logout without penalty.");
                        removeUser[rx] = p;
                        rx = rx + 1;
                    } else {
                        if(Bukkit.getServer().getOnlinePlayers().length > 0) {
                            if(ax > 0) {
                                addUser[(ax - 1)] = p;
                                x[(ax - 1)] = i;
                            } else {
                                addUser[ax] = p;
                                x[ax] = i;
                            }
                            ax = ax + 1;
                        }
                    }
                }

                int rx1 = 0;
                int ax1 = 0;
                while(rx1 <= (rx - 1)) {
                    PvpProtect.this.tagged.remove(removeUser[(rx1)]);
                    rx1 = rx1 + 1;
                }

                while(ax1 <= (ax - 1)) {
                    if(ax1 > 0) {
                        PvpProtect.this.tagged.put(addUser[(ax1 - 1)], Integer.valueOf(x[(ax1 - 1)]));
                    } else {
                        PvpProtect.this.tagged.put(addUser[ax1], Integer.valueOf(x[ax1]));
                    }
                    ax1 = ax1 + 1;
                }
            }
        }, 20L, 20L);
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onCommandProcessed(PlayerCommandPreprocessEvent e) {
        String message = e.getMessage();
        String[] subpars = message.split(" ");
        Player p = e.getPlayer();
        if ((subpars[0].replace("/", "").equalsIgnoreCase("fly")) && (this.tagged.containsKey(p)) && (!p.hasPermission("pvpprotect.untagable"))) {
            p.sendMessage("§cYou cannot do /fly while tagged!");
            e.setCancelled(true);
            return;
        }
        if ((subpars[0].replace("/", "").equalsIgnoreCase("god")) && (this.tagged.containsKey(p)) && (!p.hasPermission("pvpprotect.untagable"))) {
            p.sendMessage("§cYou cannot do /god while tagged!");
            e.setCancelled(true);
            return;
        }
    }

    @EventHandler(priority=EventPriority.NORMAL)
    public void onEntityDamageByEntity(EntityDamageByEntityEvent e) {
        if (e.isCancelled()) {
            return;
        }
        if ((e.getDamager() instanceof Player)) {
            Player damager = (Player)e.getDamager();
            User du = getEss().getUserMap().getUser(damager.getName());
            if ((e.getEntity() instanceof Player)) {
                if ((!((Player)e.getEntity()).hasPermission("")) &&  (!this.tagged.containsKey((Player)e.getEntity()))) {
                    ((Player)e.getEntity()).sendMessage("§4You are combat tagged! You cannot use modes s/a fly or god AND cannot logout without death!");
                }
                this.tagged.put((Player)e.getEntity(), Integer.valueOf(7));
            }
            if (du.isFlying()) {
                if (!(e.getEntity() instanceof Player)) {
                    if (!damager.hasPermission("pvpprotect.flypvp.mob")) {
                        damager.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "You must turn off flying to hurt mobs");
                        e.setCancelled(true);
                    }
                } else if (!damager.hasPermission("pvpprotect.flypvp.player")) {
                    damager.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "You must turn off flying to hurt players");
                    e.setCancelled(true);
                    return;
                }
            }
            if (du.isGodModeEnabled()) {
                if (!(e.getEntity() instanceof Player)) {
                    if (!damager.hasPermission("pvpprotect.godpvp.mob")) {
                        damager.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "You must turn off god to hurt mobs.");
                        e.setCancelled(true);
                    }
                } else if (!damager.hasPermission("pvpprotect.godpvp.player")) {
                    damager.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "You must turn off god to hurt players.");
                    e.setCancelled(true);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerLogout(PlayerQuitEvent e) {
        if (this.tagged.containsKey(e.getPlayer())) {
            e.getPlayer().setHealth(0);
            Bukkit.broadcastMessage("§c" + e.getPlayer().getName() + " died from §6Pvp-logging! §cDon't be an idiot like him, fight your battles");
        }
    }

    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
        if (label.equalsIgnoreCase("pvprot")) {
            sender.sendMessage("§aPvpProtection v 1.1");
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public Essentials getEss() {
        Plugin plugin = Bukkit.getPluginManager().getPlugin("Essentials");
        if ((plugin instanceof Essentials)) {
            return (Essentials)plugin;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the exact error you're getting?

Comment: Which line is line 53? Don't make us try and count your lines.

Comment: IndexOutOfBounds means you are trying to index into the array but this is outside the bounds of the array

Comment: Most of us have heard of Minecraft. Have you heard of a search box? There's one at the top of this web page, in the upper right hand corner. Type '[java] array index out of bounds' and have a look at one of the hundreds of virtually identical questions that have been asked, and you'll have your solution.

Comment: looks like the error happens here `removeUser[rx] = p;`

Comment: ArrayIndexOutOfBounds means that (duh!) you tried to index an array with an index value that was too large (or negative).  The exception stack tells you where the error occurred, so it's a very simple task to find the line, insert println statements ahead of it to print out the array size and the index value you're using, and figure out what is not as you expected.  (Or you can use an interactive debugger to do this.)  Once you've done that, and have not been able to identify the cause for the bad data, then you can come back and ask another question.

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` indicates that you're trying to assign a value to a position in an array that is invalid. For example, if you have an array of length 5, trying to put something in position 10 will throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. (Remember, too, that array positions start at 0, so our array of length 5 has elements at positions 0-4.)

Line 53 of your code is this:

```
addUser[(ax - 1)] = p;
```

If this line is throwing `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds`, then it stands to reason that you're trying to put something into the `addUser` array that won't fit.

Now your exception indicates that you're trying to put something at position 1 (which is to say, `ax` = 2), but your `addUser` array is of size 1.

You need to guard your loops with a condition along the lines of `(ax - 1) < addUser.length` to keep from trying to add items past the end of the array.

Answer (score 0):

your error is most likely happening at this line:

`removeUser[rx] = p;`

when you create an array like here

```
Player[] removeUser = new Player[] {null};
```

it's size is not dynamic so if you are expecting its size to increase and do not want to worry about managing the array size and copying, use Java ArrayList